# c loop function computing time complexity

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

I am learning to compute the time complexity of algorithms.
Simple loops and nested loops can be compute but how can I compute if there are assignments inside the loop.
For example :

```
void f(int n){
    int count=0;
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
        if(i%2==0){
            count++;
        }
        else{
            i=(i-1)*i;
        }
    }
}
```

`i = (i-1)*i` affects how many times the loop will run. How can I compute the time complexity of this function?

Comment: I don't think there is a general rule for this. In this case, it seems like `i` gets doubled every other iteration, so this should be roughly O(logn).

Comment: Does an exponential increase indicate a logarithmic increase? Sorry I'm a little new on this subject. Can you explain in more detail? @tobias_k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `i * (i-1)` is even all the time (`(i * (i-1)) % 2 == 0`), if the else part will be true for one time in the loop, `i++` makes the `i` odd number. As result, after the first odd `i` in the loop, always the condition goes inside the `else` part.

Therefore, as after the first iteration, `i` will be equal to `3` which is odd and goes inside the `else` part, `i` will be increased by `i * (i-1) +‌ 1` in each iteration. Hence, if we denote the time complexity of the loop by `T(n)`, we can write asymptotically: `T(n) = T(\sqrt(n)) + 1`. So, if `n = 2^{2^k}`, `T(n) = k = log(log(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general rule to calculate the time complexity for such algorithms. You have to use your knowledge of mathematics to get the complexity.

For this particular algorithm, I would approach it like this.

Since initially i=2 and it is even, let's ignore that first iteration.
So I am only considering from i=3. From there I will always be odd.

Your expression `i = (i-1)*i` along with the `i++` in the for loop finally evaluates to `i = (i-1)*i+1`

If you consider i=3 as 1st iteration and i(j) is the value of i in the jth iteration, then i(1)=3.
Also

`i(j) = [i(j-1)]^2 - i(j-1) + 1`

The above equation is called a recurrence relation and there are standard mathematical ways to solve it and get the value of i as a function of j. Sometimes it is possible to get and sometimes it might be very difficult or impossible. Frankly, I don't know how to solve this one.

But generally, we don't get situations where you need to go that far. In practical situations, I would just assume that the complexity is logarithmic because the value of i is increasing exponentially.